# Confused about "Remote Debugging" Wildfly 20 from Eclipse 2020-06

Tags: eclipse, wildfly, remote-debugging

I need to be able to "remotely debug" a Java/Jakarta EE servlet running under Wildfly 20 under Ubuntu 20 from Eclipse 2020-06 running on Windows 10 at a different IP.

My research has discovered what appears to be two different approaches:  one is what I want and the other is a simpler "subset".

*** First the "simple" approach.  This approach is supposed to let me debug from Eclipse an app that is already deployed and running on Wildfly. To do this I uncomment this line in standalone.conf:
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"

Then I start Wildfly and ensure the app also starts.

In Eclipse I create in Debug Configuration a new Remote Java Application and ensure I use the same port 8787 as above. Then I just push "Debug".

I get this error:
Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused. Connection refused: connect

If I return to the Wildfly system and run the following I see that port 8787 is not being monitored so that sure looks like a problem:
ss -tp | grep 8787

(nothing is found)

*** The other approach appears to be what I want to do which is to have Eclipse deploy changed files to Wildfly and also allow me to debug remotely.  That is how I worked with Eclipse Oxygen and Wildfly 10 when both were installed on the same Windows machine.

In this case I set up a new Remote Connection in Eclipse and then a new Server (and attach my Project to the Server) using that Connection. I then start the Server in Debug mode. In the Progress View I can see files being copied to a Path on the Wildfly server so that seems like progress but after 20 seconds I see the same error I got in the "simple" approach above.
Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.

What's interesting is that if, in the Remote Systems View I open the Remote Connection I created, I am able to use the sftp item to see files on the remote Wildfly system. So it seems that I am able to connect to Wildfly.

I need help fixing both of these problems but especially the last one since I need to have Eclipse deploy changes to Wildfly as it did when Wildfly was local.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What host did you use to try to connect to your server to debug? Do you have that port open in your firewall?

Comment: Why not just use --debug option in your wildfly command line ?

Comment: Hi nitind, Thanks for the response. The host is the Wildfly server's IP address on my LAN. As I described in my post above when I start Debug on the server I defined in Eclipse the Progress View shows Project files being copied to the remote Wildfly server so doesn't that confirm I have a connection between Eclipse and Wildfly? The problem is that after deploying the files the Server says "Starting, Synchronized" and it shows an animated moving icon for about 5 mins and then I changes to "Stop". Any other ideas? Again, thanks.

Comment: Hi ehsavoie. Thanks for the suggestion but I failed to state that I am starting the server with .standalone.sh --debug. Any other ideas? Thanks.